# Quick way to find all static objects

Tags: c++

I'd like to identify where all the objects of static storage duration are , in a large codebase; so that I can review to see if there are any potential problems with static initialization order.

Is there a good way to do this?

Merely searching the keyword `static` is not good enough, as it will miss any objects declared at namespace scope.

The linker's map file does indicate how big `bss` and `data` areas are , however it has all the names stripped out for symbols that are not `extern`.

Currently I am sifting through a dump of each object file looking for DATA and BSS, however that is painful and there is a lot of junk such as class vtables and compiler-generated static data.

Comment: May be inspecting the results of [`nm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) could being helpful to do this.

Comment: This really is an exercise in frustration indeed. I managed to progress a bit (I think), but could not recover the names. Hopefully someone will come with a better solution.

Comment: I'm using a different toolchain that has a similar dump utility to `nm` ; the problem is that there is so much stuff in there that it's very time-consuming to sort out which ones are static objects, and where the corresponding code is

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: this is a fairly localized and incomplete answer. I leave it here in the hope that someone may benefit from it still (and maybe build on it).*

Using the gcc toolchain, at startup `__main` calls `__do_global_ctors` which does a backward traversal of `__CTOR_LIST__`. Using `nm` on a `.so` library, for example, I get:

```
00000000004e2040 d __CTOR_END__
00000000004e2000 d __CTOR_LIST__
00000000004e2050 d __DTOR_END__
00000000004e2048 d __DTOR_LIST__
```

From then on, I suppose you could get from those addresses to the effective functions being executed; however, as you noticed, mapping back to the source name might be awkward (especially in anonymous namespaces). You may be able to recover them from the debugging information though (source location), however I have not progressed so far.